# In CrafterCMS, how can I publish a content through an API?

Tags: api, content-management-system, crafter-cms

I'm trying to write a bash script that would publish a list of files already present in crafter.

Is there an API to do that? And I suppose you need to be logged in first.

Thank you

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: That would be 2.5.x.

Comment: I was wondering if this api stays the same in crafter 3.0 ?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the Bulk Publish API, like this:

`POST /api/1/services/api/1/deployment/bulk-golive.json?site={siteName}&path={path}&environment={env}`

You will need to be logged in, so login and save the cookie to use when calling this API.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to sumerz response you could use this to log in

```
curl -i -b cookies.txt -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*"  -c cookies.txt -X POST -d "username=admin&password=admin" http://localhost:8080/studio/api/1/services/api/1/user/login.json
```

then you could use **-b** and **-c** to make curl aware of a session.